# Bash - run one script when previous is sucessful else run another script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, control-flow

I think my question is similar to [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184502/bash-how-to-run-a-command-after-the-previous-finished/184503) but with one extrat step - say I have 3 scripts:

1. main_script.sh
2. report_success.sh
3. report_failure.sh

How can I do something like this pseudo-code does:

```
if (main_script.sh finished without error):
run report_success.sh
else:
run report_failure.sh
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you are aware tht the syntax you show is not bash. It looks like python.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I just edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `main_script.sh` is fairly standard and passes a `0` for a successful run and `1` for an unsuccessful run, you can probe the status via `$?` like so:

```
./main_script.sh
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    ./report_success.sh
else
    ./report_failure.sh
fi
```

Comment: There is almost never a reason to compare or even use `$?` directly, unless you need to save it for later (which you don't need to here).

Answer (score 5):

```
if main_script.sh; then
    report_success.sh
else
    report_failure.sh
fi
```

This uses the exit status of `main_script.sh` to determine whether it was successful (exit status 0) or not (exit status non-zero) and then runs the appropriate report script.

Answer (score 2):

It's as simple as this:

`true && echo ok || echo fail`

`false && echo ok || echo fail`

A typical command may return null (as *true* does) or may return not null (as *false* does) depending on whether the operation succeeded or failed.

`./main_script.sh && ./report_success.sh || ./report_failure.sh`

If you had to run several commands for the ok or fail case, use braces. No need for several scripts:

`./main_script.sh && { echo ok ; echo ok2 } || { echo fail ; echo fail2 ; }`

Comment: Note that your commands with `&&` and `||` would run `./report_failure.sh` if _either_ of `./main_script.sh` or `./report_success.sh` failed.  This is not the same thing as an explicit `if-then-else`.

Comment: Well, yes. But failure of the success report is a failure, too.