# How do I set up ssh port forwarding and run a curl in a single command?

Tags: ssh, curl

I want to set up port forwarding with ssh like so:

```
ssh user@10.10.10.10 -L 5656:remoteserver:80 -N
```

and then run a curl command:

```
curl http://localhost:5656/my/endpoint/
```

I can accomplish this just fine using two commands, but how can I combine them into a single working command?

I'm on OSX if that matters.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Consecutive commands](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184493/consecutive-commands)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you really need to do both of the things? Would not be easier to curl on the remote server and pull the result without port forwarding, such as

```
ssh user@10.10.10.10 curl http://remoteserver/my/endpoint/ -o - > result
```

Comment: You're right. I was overthinking this problem. Thanks!